# Issue with VBA Excel number formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of about 450,000 9-digit numbers that are being used to determine the output of another column. Why is the process recognizing the nine digit numbers that start with the number 3 but not 0?

```
Sub Anything()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

Set rng = Range("Y2:Y" & Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cl In rng.Cells

    Dim outCell1 As Range
    Set outCell1 = cl.Offset(0, 54)


     Select Case Trim(cl.Value)

        Case "001019147"
            outCell1.Value = "thing1"

        Case "311019147"
            outCell1.Value = "thing2"
```

All the cells in the column contain 9-digit numbers and although there are about 450,000 cells in the column only about 2000 are processed. Any input?

Comment: likely a data type casting issue.  the system may be casting your cl.value to numeric data type dropping 00.  In excel at the top if you put `OPTION STRICT` it will show you if that's occurring by throwing an error. What is the data type?  Is it always numeric?  if so ensure both sides are numeric by specifically casting them as such.

Comment: My guess is that "001019147" is a number displayed with leading zeros so cl.Value is really 1019147.

Comment: Excel does love to auto-type cells.  Leading zeroes are especially problematic.  Difficult to say without knowing how you've formatted those cells.

Comment: All the cells in the column contain 9-digit numbers and although there are about 450,000 cells in the column only about 2000 are processed. Any input?

Comment: How many of those 9-digit numbers are less than `100,000,000`? Because if you're checking numbers against strings, leading 0's won't count.i.e. `"099999999" <> 99999999`

Comment: All of them are less than 1,000,000.

Comment: I have similar code that uses strings  instead of numbers and it works great but since I have been using the 9-digit numbers there has been this issue.

Comment: Actually, ignore what I said above, I tried this code in vba `"0999" = 999` and it returned `true`. I might need to look into this further.

Comment: @SCB that is interesting, but I still think it depends on the formatting.  If the cells are still stored as numbers and not strings, say with formatting = "000000000".  Then the string comparison will fail with leading zeroes, but succeed with entries without leading zeroes

Comment: Thank you so much. Stack Overflow is such a great enviroment!!!

Comment: It's too cold.  I really can't tell if that's sarcasm or not.

Comment: @jrq very interesting. And that's actually caused some weird results that I'm wondering about, but it's a bit to much and a bit to off topic to post in these comments, so I asked a new question about it: [strange ways comparisons occur](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552278/strange-ways-comparisons-occur)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

**Select Case Trim(cl.Text)**

Answer (score 1):

For your `select case` statement, try using

```
Select Case Val(Trim(cl.Value))

    Case 1019147
        outCell1.Value = "thing1"

    Case 311019147
        outCell1.Value = "thing2"
```

This will allow you to have values and/or multiple values.
e.g.

```
Case 1 to 22
Case 1,2,3,57,999
Case 1 to 8,300,400 to 499
```

Comment: Using the "Val" function is the key here.  This gets around the leading zero problem, you can even keep the comparison as strings and it still works.