# Strange ways comparisons occur

Tags: vba, excel

This is something strange that I've come across looking at this question here: [Issue with VBA Excel number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551182/issue-with-vba-excel-number-formatting) I thought I might expand on it and see if anyone can explain.

Lets say I have an Excel document with 5 cells in column `A` all with the value `1234`

- The first is formatted with the format string `"000000000"`
- The second is formatted using Excel's "Number" format
- The third is formatted as Excel's "General" format
- The fourth is formatted as "Text"
- The fifth is formatted as "Text" but is actually the string `"000001234"`

As such, the excel table looks like this

```
     A    |
----------+-
 000001234|
   1234.00|
      1234|
1234      |
000001234 |
```

Now I run the following code, base slightly on the question mentioned above.

```
Sub test3()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        If 1234 = "000001234" Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = "A"
        End If
        If 1234 = cl.Value Then
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "B"
        End If
        If "000001234" = cl.Value Then
            cl.Offset(0, 3).Value = "C"
        End If
    Next cl

End Sub
```

And the output is as follows

```
     A    | B | C | D |
----------+---+---+---+-
 000001234| A | B |   |
   1234.00| A | B |   |
      1234| A | B |   |
1234      | A | B |   |
000001234 | A | B | C |
```

The column `B` makes sense. VBA can compare Strings as if they're numbers, and by extensions the column `C` makes sense as well, in each case, we're either comparing numbers to numbers as in the first 3 rows, or doing a similar string comparison in the last 2 rows.

However the column `D` gets me and is basically my question.

If `1234 = "000001234"` and `1234 = cl.Value` then why doesn't `"000001234" = cl.Value` in all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of `cl.Value` is either **vbDouble** (first 3 sample rows) or **vbString** (other two), see [VarType() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278470(v=office.15).aspx). But during the comparison, there is type casting.
Therefore

- comparing values to number `1234` will always succeed, becaue doubles and strings in `cl.Value` are converted to number (integer) before comparison. Leading zeros get insignificant during conversion to number.
- comparing values to string `"000001234"` will succeed only in case of string `000001234` because `cl.Value` is converted to string before comparison so for your first sample row `"000001234" <> "1234"` (see what happens to `cl.Value`: `000001234` → `1234` → `"1234"`). For other rows, it is similar: `1234.00` → `1234` → `"1234"` and this is again not equal to `"000001234"` etc.